# Postman won't POST to ASP.Net WebAPI 2 controller, but GET works

Tags: c#, .net, postman, asp.net-web-api2

I can't seem to get my webapi to work in PostMan and it gives me a 404 when POSTing, but works only when using GET (even though the api specifically set to accept only POSTs! - go figure!)

Here's the controller code (that works) - NOTE: I can't use formdata as this is dotnet fw 4.72

```
    [Route("api/GetProfile")]
    [HttpPost]        
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProfile(string UserId)
    {
        var retval = new Profile();
        if (UserId != null)
        {
            if (await dbv.IsValidUserIdAsync(UserId))
            {
                retval = await profile_Data.GetProfileAsync(UserId);
            }
        }
        return Ok(retval);
    }
```

The code works fine for GET (even though it's set to accept POST!), which it shouldn't.

In PostMan, the URI is
https://localhost:44371/api/GetProfile
The route is 100% correct!

On the Body tab, it is set to RAW and the following JSON is inside

```
{"UserId" : "69d40311-f9e0-4499-82ea-959949fc34fe"}
```

The parameter is 100% correct!
The error when attempting to POST is

```
   {
        "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44371/api/GetProfile'.",
        "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Accounts' that matches the request."
    }
```

If I put the parameters in the querystring, it works (even though the controller is set to accept POST).
If I change the controller to GET and PostMan to GET (and set the parameters in params), it works.

Is PostMan not compatible with ASP.Net webapi 2.0 ?
Why would GET work and POST not work? Makes no sense?

Comment: Without seeing all your code, including your configuration, middleware, etc. it's impossible to know what's happening.

Comment: Have you tried posting only the string (with quotes)? Is the ContentType set correctly? You could also try to add a `[FromBody]` attribute to the parameter.

Comment: I added the [FromBody] attribute and it works now from PostMan.  Apparently, it works without the attribute when calling from AJAX, but not from PostMan.
To answer rory.ap: there is no middleware and no configuration outside of the controller - I'm using FW4.72, not Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set Content-Type `application/json` on postman and in your controller's `POST` method add the attribute `FromBody`

> [FromBody] isn't inferred for simple types such as string or int. Therefore, the [FromBody] attribute should be used for simple types when that functionality is needed.

```
    [Route("api/GetProfile")]
    [HttpPost]        
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProfile([FromBody] string UserId)
    {
        var retval = new Profile();
        if (UserId != null)
        {
            if (await dbv.IsValidUserIdAsync(UserId))
            {
                retval = await profile_Data.GetProfileAsync(UserId);
            }
        }
        return Ok(retval);
    }
```

Also consider to return `CreatedAtAction` or `CreatedAtRoute` instead of `Ok`

Comment: CreatedAtAction is Core only, I'll look into CreatedAtRoute (which is available).